# How can I speed up my Office Scripts code so that it doesn't fail in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

I have been asked to pull data from an Excel online spreadsheet on Sharepoint into Power BI to create a dashboard - no problem, right? Well, one of the 'data points' is actually fill colour of the cell indicating status. I did some googling and managed to write an Office Script that translates the fill colour to the status and got everything to work but I was still running the Office Script manually (and it was taking 3 hours to run).

So I turned to Power Automate and scheduled it to run the script, but it fails every time and I think it's to do with how long the Office Script takes to run because when I reduce the range that it's running over (significantly) it works. Any help to solve this will be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  
  //disable auto calculation mode

  workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.manual);

  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("ProjectsColourFill");
  let projects = workbook.getWorksheet("Projects");
  // Paste range at 1:1048576 on selectedSheet from 1:1048576 on projects
  selectedSheet.getRange("1:1048576").copyFrom(projects.getRange("1:1048576"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);

  let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  // Paste range at E3 on selectedSheet from E1:NP1 on sheet1
  selectedSheet.getRange("E3").copyFrom(sheet1.getRange("E1:NP1"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);

  selectedSheet.getRange("3:3").setNumberFormatLocal("dd/mm/yyyy;@");

  let cell = selectedSheet.getRange("H7");
  let format = cell.getFormat().getFill().getColor();

  let range = selectedSheet.getRange("H7:NP320");

  // Get the size boundaries of the range.
  let rows = range.getRowCount();
  let cols = range.getColumnCount();


  // Iterate over the range.
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {


      if (range.getCell(row, col).getValue() != "") {
         // Get colour of current cell

           // If colour is one of the three status, fill with status
        if (range.getCell(row, col).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == '#DA9694') {
                range.getCell(row,col).setValue("Planned Dates TBC");
            }
        if (range.getCell(row, col).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == '#92D050') {
              range.getCell(row, col).setValue("Booked");
            }
        if (range.getCell(row, col).getFormat().getFill().getColor() == '#E26B0A') {
              range.getCell(row, col).setValue("Prospective");
            }
  
      }
     // console.log(range.getCell(row,col).getAddress());

    }
  }

  //turn it back on
  workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.automatic);


}
```

Comment: A long time ago I used to program with VBA a lot. I remember I could speed things up significantly when disabling screen updating. I added this line at the start of time consuming code: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few things you can consider:

- Avoid Excel API calls as much as possible inside loops.
- Try to capture API results into variables if they can be reused.
- Instead of iterating through cells and calling `cell.getValue()`, try retrieving all the values of the whole range into a two-dimensional array (i.e, `let values = range.getValues()`) and iterating through that array.
- Same thing when setting cell values - use `range.setValues(values)` instead of calling `cell.setValue()` repetitively inside a loop.
- Instead of tackling with all the cells in the whole worksheet, try things like `worksheet.getUsedRange()` to work on only the cells that have values.
- This articles talks about some good performance tips: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/web-client-performance.

Below is my attempt to optimize some of your code. I'm sure there are still room for improvement (e.g., switch to `getUsedRange()`, etc.), but hopefully you can get the idea of it:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  //disable auto calculation mode
  workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.manual);

  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("ProjectsColourFill");
  let projects = workbook.getWorksheet("Projects");
  // Paste range at 1:1048576 on selectedSheet from 1:1048576 on projects
  selectedSheet.getRange("1:1048576").copyFrom(projects.getRange("1:1048576"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);

  let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  // Paste range at E3 on selectedSheet from E1:NP1 on sheet1
  selectedSheet.getRange("E3").copyFrom(sheet1.getRange("E1:NP1"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);

  selectedSheet.getRange("3:3").setNumberFormatLocal("dd/mm/yyyy;@");

  let cell = selectedSheet.getRange("H7");
  let format = cell.getFormat().getFill().getColor();

  let range = selectedSheet.getRange("H7:NP320");
  let values = range.getValues();

  // Get the size boundaries of the range.
  let rows = range.getRowCount();
  let cols = range.getColumnCount();

  // Iterate over the range.
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

      if (values[row][col] != "") {
        // Get colour of current cell
        let color = range.getCell(row, col).getFormat().getFill().getColor();

        // If colour is one of the three status, fill with status
        if (color == '#DA9694') {
          values[row][col] = "Planned Dates TBC";
        }
        if (color == '#92D050') {
          values[row][col] = "Booked";
        }
        if (color == '#E26B0A') {
          values[row][col] = "Prospective";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  range.setValues(values);

  //turn it back on
  workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.automatic);
}
```